# How to get authentication token and refresh token from TwitchAPI

Tags: python, authentication, twitch-api

I need to know how I get the authentication token and the refresh token from the TwitchAPI using python. I have read through most of this [documentation](https://pytwitchapi.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/v2.2.2/pdf/) about the subject and I have copied the code on page 53 but it does not work. When I run the code a new tab pops up (as it should) but when I click continue the site cannot be reached for some reason. I am using https://localhost as my redirect URL and I am certain that my app id and secret are correct.

Thanks for the help in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine helped me solve it and the answer was that instead of `http://localhost` I needed to use `http://localhost:17563`.